# UMDF Detect Display State (On/Dim/Off) from System Reboot/Restart Events

Tags: c, .net, driver, wdk, umdf

Using [PowerSettingRegisterNotification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/powersetting/nf-powersetting-powersettingregisternotification), I was able to listen to Display States on the following System Power Events (using `GUID_CONSOLE_DISPLAY_STATE` as SettingGUID):

- System Shutdown
- Sleep
- Hibernate
- User Idle (Turn screen off after n-minutes)

What I was not able to receive a Display State from is when a system restart is performed. My Power Setting Notify Callback was not called, neither from Display State Off before restart, nor Display State On after restarting.

Is this a normal behavior? Or should I be listening to another event, specifically to handle this kind of scenario?

EDIT: I also tried `GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON` as my SettingGUID, the same behavior was produced.

Comment: in all of the above, the Driver is still in memory (assume you are using fast boot),  but in D3, I would think that in Reset the driver is unloaded before you are getting the Callback, why not using D3Exit state for that?

Comment: I tried using `EvtWdfDeviceD0Exit` for that, with `WdfPowerDeviceD3Final` as `WDF_POWER_DEVICE_STATE`. The driver was not notified of such exit from D0 during system restart or system shutdown. I also tried the other states, the only D0 Exit the driver received was from `WdfPowerDevicePrepareForHibernation` for pre-hibernation.